# Relationship between Apache Kafka and Confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am learning Kafka recently.

What is the relationship between Kafka and Confluent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) is an open-source Stream Processing Platform with a message broker/pub-sub system in its core and Java Producer/Consumer client libraries to read/write data from an application, Kafka Connect framework to import/export data from Kafka, and Kafka Streams library to process data stored in Kafka.

[Confluent Inc.](https://www.confluent.io/) is a company and the main contributor to Apache Kafka: Top 10 contributors are all working at Confluent; including 10 Committers (including myself) (pages accessed May 2018):

- https://github.com/apache/kafka/graphs/contributors
- https://kafka.apache.org/committers

Additionally, Confluent adds [additional tools](https://www.confluent.io/product/compare/) on top of Apache Kafka. Those tools are offered as [Confluent Open Source and Confluent Enterprise](https://www.confluent.io/product/) which both ship with Apache Kafka.

Confluent Open Source adds a KSQL, Rest Proxy, Schema Registry, Connectors for Kafka Connect, as well as Producer/Consumer client libraries in other languages (e.g., C/C++, Python).

Confluent Enterprise adds "Confluent Control Center" (a cluster and application monitoring tool), a multi-datacenter replication tool, and an auto-data-balancing feature. Additionally, you get 24/7 support.

Confluent also offers [Confluent Cloud](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-cloud/), a hosted and fully managed solution for Apache Kafka.